# <identifier> expected error while creating object list

Tags: java, debugging, compiler-errors

Can someone help me resolve this innocuous Identifier expected error? I am declaring a Register class and trying to make a list of Register objects.

**UPDATE** : 'Register' is locally scoped in MySaxParser.java as Meesh suggested. But I still see identifier expected error. The complete code and error message is below:

The issue was seen using java version "1.4.1_01"

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;



public class MySaxParser extends DefaultHandler {
    List<Register> registerL;
    String xmlFileName;
    String tmpValue;
    Register registerTmp;

    public MySaxParser(String xmlFileName) {
        this.xmlFileName = xmlFileName;
        registerL = new ArrayList<Register>();
        parseDocument();
        printDatas();
    }
    private void parseDocument() {
        // parse
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
            parser.parse(xmlFileName, this);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            System.out.println("ParserConfig error");
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("SAXException : xml not well formed");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO error");
        }
    }
    private void printDatas() {
       // System.out.println(bookL.size());
        for (Register tmpReg : registerL) {
            System.out.println(tmpReg.toString());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void startElement(String s, String s1, String elementName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // if current element is book , create new book
        // clear tmpValue on start of element

        if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase("reg")) {
            registerTmp = new Register();
            registerTmp.setregName(attributes.getValue("regname"));
            registerTmp.setaddr(attributes.getValue("addr"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ac, int i, int j) throws SAXException {
        tmpValue = new String(ac, i, j);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MySaxParser("register.xml");
    }
}



/*****
 * Model class for Regsiter
 * ****/
 class Register { 
   String regName;
   String addr;

   //Setters 
   public void setregName(String regName ) {     this.regName = regName; } 
   public void setaddr (String addr ) {     this.addr = addr; } 

   //Getters
    public String getregName() {    return this.regName; } 
    public String getaddr() { return this.addr;}

}
```

**ERROR:**

```
MySaxParser.java:19: <identifier> expected
    List<Register> registerL;
        ^
MySaxParser.java:26: '(' or '[' expected
        registerL = new ArrayList<Register>();
                                 ^
MySaxParser.java:46: ';' expected
        for (Register tmpReg : registerL) {
                             ^
MySaxParser.java:49: illegal start of expression
    }
    ^
MySaxParser.java:48: ';' expected
        }
         ^
MySaxParser.java:50: illegal character: \64
    @Override
    ^
MySaxParser.java:62: illegal character: \64
    @Override
    ^
MySaxParser.java:68: <identifier> expected
    }
     ^
MySaxParser.java:26: cannot resolve symbol
symbol  : variable registerL 
location: class MySaxParser
        registerL = new ArrayList<Register>();
        ^
9 errors
```

Comment: Are both classes in the same file? I don't think you can declare them both public.

Comment: but error shouldn't be about public class has to be declared in a file name MySaxParser.java??? I don't understand this explain please

Comment: You're right Aayush, I get this error when I tried it:
`The public type MySaxParser must be defined in its own file`, and not `<identifier> expected`. Nik can you provide more info?

Comment: Are you using Java5+ syntax? Otherwise it won't like the type annotation.

Comment: @Thilo Im using "1.4.1_01". is that an issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both `Register` and `MySaxParser` are public classes (meaning that they can be used by other classes), they both need to be in a file of their own. If not, you can make `Register` locally scoped, and access it only in `MySaxParser`. For example (details omitted for brevity):

```
public class MySaxParser {
    List<Register> registers;
}

class Register {
    String value;
}
```

Also, see @Thilo's comment above. You may need to change your use of generics depending on which JRE/JDK you're using.

Comment: Ah looks like you won't be able to use generics, unless you upgrade your runtime. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146197/does-java-1-4-have-generics

Comment: I see.. Im running it in a java 1.7 env and this error isnt there.  I do see an IO exception thrown which Im debugging

Answer (score 2):

```
java version "1.4.1_01"    

List<Register> registerL;
```

That is a really old Java version. Generics have been introduced in Java5, so in order to use "modern" Java, you need to update to a newer version.

Comment: Thanks, resolved this with a 'modern' version! However I do see an IO exception being thrown that I am debugging. Do you know what could be the issue? The file registers.xml is in same directory.

Answer (score 0):

It may be compilation error. So, you need to write these two class within same package.